# For Loop to Rename Column Names of Many Objects R

Tags: r, for-loop, quantmod

I am looking for a way to rename the columns of several objects with a for loop or other method in R. Ultimately, I want to be able to bind the rows of each Stock object into one large data frame, but cannot due to differing column names. Example below:

```
AAPL <-
Date        AAPL.Open  AAPL.High AAPL.Low  AAPL.Close  AAPL.Volume  AAPL.Adjusted  Stock  pct_change
2020-05-14  304.51     309.79    301.53    309.54      39732300     309.54         AAPL   0.61
2020-05-15  300.35     307.90    300.21    307.71      41561200     307.71         AAPL  -0.59


GOOG <-  
Date        GOOG.Open GOOG.High  GOOG.Low  GOOG.Close  GOOG.Volume   GOOG.Adjusted  Stock  pct_change 
2020-05-14  1335.02   1357.420   1323.910  1356.13     1603100       1356.13        GOOG   0.50
2020-05-15  1350.00   1374.480   1339.000  1373.19     1705700       1373.19        GOOG   1.26
```

For this example I have 2 objects (AAPL and GOOG), but realistically I would be working with many more. Can I create a for loop to iterate through each object, and rename the 2nd column of each to "Open", 3rd column to "High", 4th column to "Low",.... etc so I can then bind all these objects together?

I already have a column named "Stock", so I do not need the Ticker part of the column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `quantmod` we can read a set of stock ticker symbols, clean their names & `rbind()` into a single data frame.

There are three key features illustrated within this answer, including:

1. Use of `get()` to access the objects written by `quantmod::getSymbols()` once they are loaded into memory.
2. Use of the symbol names passed into `lapply()` to add a `symbol` column to each data frame.
3. Conversion of the dates stored as row names in the `xts` objects written by `getSymbols()` to a data frame column.

First, we'll use `getSymbols()` to read data from yahoo.com.

```
library(quantmod)
from.dat <- as.Date("12/02/19",format="%m/%d/%y")
to.dat <- as.Date("12/06/19",format="%m/%d/%y")

theSymbols <- c("AAPL","AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","XOM","GS","HD","IBM",
                "INTC","JNJ","KO","JPM","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG",
                "TRV","UNH","UTX","VZ","V","WBA","WMT","DIS","DOW")
getSymbols(theSymbols,from=from.dat,to=to.dat,src="yahoo")

# since quantmod::getSymbols() writes named data frames, need to use
# get() with the symbol names to access each data frame
head(get(theSymbols[[1]]))



> head(get(theSymbols[[1]]))
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2019-12-02    267.27    268.25   263.45     264.16    23621800      262.8231
2019-12-03    258.31    259.53   256.29     259.45    28607600      258.1370
2019-12-04    261.07    263.31   260.68     261.74    16795400      260.4153
2019-12-05    263.79    265.89   262.73     265.58    18606100      264.2359
```

Having illustrated how to access the symbol objects in the global environment, we'll use `lapply()` to extract the dates from the row names, clean the column headings, and write the symbol name as a column for each symbol's data object.

```
# convert to list
symbolData <- lapply(theSymbols,function(x){
     y <- as.data.frame(get(x))
     colnames(y) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adjusted")
     y$date <- rownames(y)
     y$symbol <- x
     y
})
```

Finally, we convert the list of data frames to a single data frame.

```
#combine to single data frame
combinedData <- do.call(rbind,symbolData)
rownames(combinedData) <- 1:nrow(combinedData)
```

...and the output:

```
> nrow(combinedData)
[1] 120
> head(combinedData)
    open   high    low  close   volume adjusted       date symbol
1 267.27 268.25 263.45 264.16 23621800 262.8231 2019-12-02   AAPL
2 258.31 259.53 256.29 259.45 28607600 258.1370 2019-12-03   AAPL
3 261.07 263.31 260.68 261.74 16795400 260.4153 2019-12-04   AAPL
4 263.79 265.89 262.73 265.58 18606100 264.2359 2019-12-05   AAPL
5 120.31 120.36 117.07 117.26  5538200 116.2095 2019-12-02    AXP
6 116.04 116.75 114.65 116.57  3792300 115.5256 2019-12-03    AXP
>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee the order of these columns this should do it:

```
for(df in list(AAPL, GOOG))
  colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted", "Stock", "pct_change")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply`, we can loop over the `list` and remove the prefix in the column names with `sub`.  This can be done without any external packages

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(AAPL, GOOG),  function(x)  {
        colnames(x) <- sub(".*\\.", "", colnames(x))
    x})
```